# Can't upload image to firebase storage

Tags: java, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to read an image and upload it to firebase storage. The file makes it into storage but when I actually go click on it in the console, I can't view it. There are no failures and the size of the image looks correct in storage. Any ideas?

```
        val ins = FileInputStream("/Users/jason/demo/src/main/kotlin/com/tandem/store/test.jpeg")
        val client = StorageClient.getInstance(app)
        val s = client.bucket()
        val blobString = "test3/" + "test.jpeg"
        s.create(blobString, ins, "image/jpeg", Bucket.BlobWriteOption.userProject("quick23hire-43424"));
```

Comment: The Firebase console is known to be unable to show previews of images that were uploaded outside of a web or mobile app.  If you can upload and download the file fine, don't worry about the preview.

Comment: Hello Brennen, could you please confirm if you can view the file successfully when downloading it from the Firebase Storage?

Comment: It does seem to be downloading fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase console is known to be unable to show previews of images that were uploaded outside of a web or mobile app. If you can upload and download the file fine, don't worry about the preview.

*(Putting the comments as an Comm. Wiki answer for better visibility)*